# Convert image (jpg) to base64 in Excel VBA?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, base64

I need to **convert an image inside Excel** (or through VBA) **to base64** (in the end I will make XML output).

How can I do this? Do I need to make a reference to DOM?

I´ve been reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba) but it only works for text strings not images...

Does anyone have any code that I can see?

Comment: how do you get that image? Clipboard, file system?

Comment: Where is your image? Is it a separate file, or is it embedded in your Excel sheet?

Comment: The image is in my file system (HD).

Answer (score 11):

Heres a function. Can't remember where I got it from.

```
Public Function EncodeFile(strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded

    ' Variables for encoding
    Dim objXML
    Dim objDocElem

    ' Variable for reading binary picture
    Dim objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)

    ' Create XML Document object and root node
    ' that will contain the data
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.dataType = "bin.base64"

    ' Set binary value
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

    ' Get base64 value
    EncodeFile = objDocElem.Text

    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```