Create an Outlook email and add an Excel Named Range and 3 Charts from a different Worksheet to the email body as images
I'm trying to modify some code from @PeterT, which adds charts as images to an Outlook email.  His code works perfectly for adding the charts to an email and is super fast (Thank you @PeterT!)
I'm trying to add an Excel Named Range (the range of the Named Range changes every month) to the email body as an image *before *the Charts.  What I have attempted thus far does capture the image to the clipboard, but then I have to manually Paste it to the email body above the Charts.
Ideally I would like to save the Range image to a temp filename like the macro/functions is doing with the Charts and then just let the macro insert the range and charts into the email body at once.
Thx,
Don
@PeterT's code with a slight modification to capture 3 specific Charts vs all the charts on the ActiveSheet:
Option Explicit

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161736/sending-a-chart-in-mail-body
'Super fast at adding the Charts to an email

Sub CreateEmail()
        Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"
        Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim olApp As Object
        Dim olMail As Object
        Dim msg As String
        Dim msgGreeting As String
        Dim msgPara1 As String
        Dim msgEnding As String
        Dim chrt As ChartObject
        Dim fname As String
        Dim ident As String
        Dim tempFiles As Collection
        Dim imgIdents As Collection
        Dim imgFile As Variant
        Dim attchmt As Object
        Dim oPa As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim chartNumbers As Variant
        Dim ii As Long
        Dim myChartObj As ChartObject
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim imgFileName As String
        
        '--- create the email body with HTML-formatted content
        msgGreeting = "<bold>Team</bold>,<br><br>"
        msgPara1 = "<div>Some Text1</div><br>" & _
                    "<div><bold>Some Text2</bold><br>" & _
                    "(Some Text3)</div><br><br>"
        msgEnding = "<br><br>Thanks,<br>MyName<br>MyTitle<br>MyPhoneNumber<br>"
        
        '--- build the other email body content
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        msg = msgGreeting & msgPara1
        
        '--- This captures a picture of the Range, but needs to be manually pasted to the email
        ' Set the range you want to copy
        Set rng = Worksheets("Daily Average").Range("DailyAverage")
        ' Copy the range as an image
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        
         '--- loops and adds all charts found on the worksheet
        If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Set tempFiles = New Collection
            Set imgIdents = New Collection
             
          '--- Use this section to loop thru all the Chart Objects on the ActiveSheet
          '    instead of using the array of specific Charts below
'            For Each chrt In ws.ChartObjects
'                fname = ""
'                msg = msg & ChartToEmbeddedHTML(chrt, fname, ident) & "<br><br>"
'                tempFiles.Add fname
'                imgIdents.Add ident
'            Next chrt

            ' Define the array of chart numbers you want to process
            'Added this section FROM HERE.....
            chartNumbers = Array(10, 15, 16)
        
            For ii = LBound(chartNumbers) To UBound(chartNumbers)
                Set myChartObj = ws.ChartObjects("Chart " & chartNumbers(ii))
            '--- This With section resizes the Charts on the ActiveSheet
'                With myChartObj
'                    .Height = 350
'                    .Width = 600
'                End With
                fname = ""
                msg = msg & ChartToEmbeddedHTML(myChartObj, fname, ident) & "<br><br>"
                tempFiles.Add fname
                imgIdents.Add ident
            Next ii
            '.....TO HERE and commented out the previous 6 lines to loop thru all the Chart Objects on the ActiveSheet
        
        End If
        msg = msg & msgEnding

        '--- create the mail item
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)                'olMailItem=0
        With olMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Signature").Range("D2").Value  '  "yyy@zzzz.com"
            .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Signature").Range("D4").Value '   "xxxx@xxx"
            .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Signature").Range("D7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")  '   "xxxx"
            .BodyFormat = 2        'olFormatHTML=2

            '--- each of the images is referenced as a filename, but each one must be
            '    individually added as an attachment, then the attachment properties
            '    set to show the attachment as "inline". Because the image will be
            '    inlined, we'll use the "ident" as the reference (internal to the
            '    message body HTML)
            If (Not tempFiles Is Nothing) Then
                For i = 1 To tempFiles.Count
                    Set attchmt = .Attachments.Add(tempFiles.Item(i))
                    Set oPa = attchmt.PropertyAccessor
                    oPa.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, "image/png"
                    oPa.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, imgIdents.Item(i)
                Next i
            End If
            '--- the email item needs to be saved first
            .Save
            '--- now add the message contents
            .HTMLBody = msg
'''--- Not finding the right place for this
''' Paste the image into the email body
'olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste
            .Display
        End With
        '--- delete the temp files now
        For Each imgFile In tempFiles
            Kill imgFile
        Next imgFile
        '--- clean up and get out
        Set tempFiles = Nothing
        Set imgIdents = Nothing
        Set attchmt = Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing
        Set oPa = Nothing
        Set olMail = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set wb = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Private Function ChartToEmbeddedHTML(thisChart As ChartObject, _
                                 ByRef tmpFile As String, _
                                 ByRef ident As String) As String
        Dim html As String
        ident = RandomString(8)
        tmpFile = thisChart.Parent.Parent.Path & "\" & ident & ".png"
        
        thisChart.Activate
        thisChart.Chart.Export FileName:=tmpFile, Filtername:="png"
        html = "<img alt='Excel Chart' src='cid:" & ident & "'></img>"
        ChartToEmbeddedHTML = html
    End Function
    
    Private Function RandomString(strlen As Integer) As String
        Dim i As Integer, iTemp As Integer, bOK As Boolean, strTemp As String
        '48-57 = 0 To 9, 65-90 = A To Z, 97-122 = a To z
        'amend For other characters If required
        For i = 1 To strlen
            Do
                iTemp = Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)
                Select Case iTemp
                Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: bOK = True
                Case Else: bOK = False
                End Select
            Loop Until bOK = True
            bOK = False
            strTemp = strTemp & Chr(iTemp)
        Next i
        RandomString = strTemp
    End Function


What I have tried is to insert this code in various places within the macro without any luck...basically it just inserts the Charts and 'ignores' the Range.Paste line.
'''--- Not finding the right place for this
''' Paste the image into the email body
'olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste


Here's an example using a different approach to add the images. Exported images (via Chart.Export are converted to B64-encoded text and embedded directly in the HTML <img> tag. This feels cleaner to me than using the "cid+attachment" method.
Option Explicit

'Create an email with some images from Excel Range/Chart
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet, html As String, olApp As Object, olMail As Object
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'for example

    html = "<p>Header here</p>"
    html = html & ToImageTag(sht.Range("B2:H8")) & "<br>"
    html = html & "<p>Footer here</p>"
    html = html & ToImageTag(sht.ChartObjects("chart1").Chart) & "<br>"
    html = html & "<p>Footer2 here</p>"
    html = html & ToImageTag(sht.Range("C18:F31")) & "<br>"
    html = html & "<p>Footer3 here</p>"
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem=0
    With olMail
        .BodyFormat = 2              'olFormatHTML=2
        .HTMLBody = html
        .display
    End With
    
End Sub

'Convert a range or chart an <img> tag for HTML,with image content encoded as B64
Function ToImageTag(obj As Object) As String
    Dim b64 As String
    If TypeName(obj) = "Range" Then
        b64 = RangeToB64(obj)
    Else 'is a chart
        b64 = ChartToB64(obj)
    End If
    ToImageTag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," & b64 & "'>"
End Function

'Convert a Range to a B64 string (via exported chart image)
Function RangeToB64(rng As Range) As String
    Dim cob, sc, i As Long
    
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set cob = rng.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 200, 200)
    Set sc = cob.Chart.SeriesCollection 'remove any series which may have been auto-added...
    Do While sc.Count > 0
        sc(1).Delete
    Loop
    With cob
        .ShapeRange.line.Visible = msoFalse  '<<< remove chart border
        .Height = rng.Height
        .Width = rng.Width
        Do
            .Chart.Paste
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Loop While i < 5 And .Chart.Shapes.Count = 0 'in case paste failed try 5 times...
        RangeToB64 = ChartToB64(.Chart)
        .Delete
    End With
End Function

'Convert chart to b64 string via exported temp file
Function ChartToB64(cht As Chart)
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = TempPath
    cht.Export FileName:=sPath, Filtername:="PNG"
    ChartToB64 = EncodeBase64(sPath)
    Kill sPath
End Function

'get a B64-encoded string from a file
Function EncodeBase64(filePath As String) As String
    Dim bytes, b64
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1 'ADODB.adTypeBinary
        .LoadFromFile filePath
        bytes = .Read
        .Close
    End With
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = bytes
        EncodeBase64 = Replace(.text, vbLf, "")
    End With
End Function

'Return a temporary file path
Function TempPath() As String
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        TempPath = .GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & .GetTempName()
    End With
End Function


This is almost it!  The issue I'm having is that there are 3 charts, so I repeated the 'html =' lines 2 more times and changed the charts to the correct numbers, but I get the error 'Error! FileName not specified'.  I'm guessing its due to the Function ToImageTag, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

The code I posted here is just an example of the general approach - it wasn't meant to replicate your use case.

If you're getting an error, please provide the exact error message and the line where it occurs.

I modified your example to fit my case. Your example allowed me to create the email, insert a Range (as chart image), then add 'Chart 10' below it. Using your format, I added 2 more 'htlm =' rows below 'Chart 10' for 'Chart 15' and 'Chart 16'. The code executes without errors and using the Locals window I can see that the tmp files for the range chart (1) and charts (3) are being created in the temp folder. The error is in the email body. Under the Range Chart and Chart 10 I get "Error! Filename not specified." twice rather than images for Chart 15 and 16.

If you open the temp files for those images what do you see?

My apologies.  I'm a little confused as to why, but as I continued to try to understand the code this morning 'all of a sudden' and after multiple executions of the code (watching the locals window), the email is/started being created as I expected.
Text, Range Chart, Text, Chart 10, Text, Chart 15, Text, Chart 16, etc...
I will mark your solution as accepted/solved.
And to answer your question I was seeing the Range Chart, then Chart 10, 15, 16 in that order.
Thank you for your help!

Good to hear it's working out now.
