# Vba Excel. Resize image when loaded from file and then encode it base64

Tags: excel, vba

With the following function ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043393/convert-image-jpg-to-base64-in-excel-vba)) can I load and then encode to base64 an image. Now I would like to resize the image (keeping width/height ratio) **before** encoding it. I'm not used to program in Vba and I did not find any example or snippet that may help me.

```
Public Function EncodeFileBase64(strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1

    Dim objXML
    Dim objDocElem

    Dim objStream

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.CreateElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"

    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

    ' EncodeFileBase64 = objDocElem.Text
    EncodeFileBase64 = Replace(objDocElem.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of temptatives the most pratical solution is:

1. resize the image
2. save the resized image to a file
3. load the saved file and apply base64 encoding to this

VBA does not have instruments to manipulate images so you must use some external software. I used ImageMagick: [take a look at my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351838/excel-vba-save-resized-image-to-file) to an other post of mine.