# How to paste image from excel sheet into gmail body via visual basic?

Tags: excel, vba, cdo.message

I wrote one macro in excel I m send mail via Gmail. I m sending message but I cannot send picture because I cannot paste picture in gmail message body . I put my code. Also I m getting picture from activesheet(Sheet4 according to my excel ). How can I add this picture in my mail message body ?

```
Sub SendGmail(frommail As String, password As String, tomail As String, subject As String, mesaj As String)
    
    Dim pic As String
    pic = CheckImageName
    
                    If pic <> "" Then
                        Sheet4.Shapes(pic).Copy
                    End If
  
    
    
    
    If frommail <> "" And password <> "" And tomail <> "" And subject <> "" And mesaj <> "" Then
      On Error Resume Next
    
       'creating a CDO object
       Dim Mail As CDO.message
       Set Mail = New CDO.message
     
       'Enable SSL Authentication
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    
       'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    
       'Set the SMTP server and port Details
       'Get these details from the Settings Page of your Gmail Account
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
       "smtp.gmail.com"
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    
       'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = _
       frommail
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = _
        password
        
    
       'Update the configuration fields
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    
       'Set All Email Properties
       With Mail
          .subject = subject
          .From = frommail
          .To = tomail
          .CC = ""
          .BCC = ""
          .HTMLBody = mesaj
       
       
        
       End With
       'to send the mail
       Mail.Send
     If Err <> 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Mail gönderme basarisiz.Eposta Ayarlari sayfasindan mail adresinizi ve sifrenizi kontrol ediniz!!!"
        Call MessageBoxTimer("HATA", "Mail gönderme basarisiz.Eposta Ayarlari sayfasindan mail adresinizi ve sifrenizi kontrol ediniz!!!")
        Exit Sub
     End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Surely if you're wanting to paste an image into the body you wouldn't use a `.TextBody` but rather `.HTMLBody`?

Comment: Yes I know .HTMLBody I put only example. I want to learn how to get picture from sheet and insert in Mail Htmlbody.

Answer (score 2):

I searched the internet for you and found two options.
They both require you to use a file on the filesystem,
the second option is not the best supported in mail clients (web or app).

So you'll have to save the image you have on your sheet to filesystem first, if it's not already there.
A solution for that can be found here: [Export pictures from excel file into jpg using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba)

#### Method 1: Use inline attachments (MIME standards)

Add to your code (and adjust the usage of your img in the html message):

```
Const CdoReferenceTypeName = 1
Mail.htmlBody = "<html>Check this out: <img src=""cid:myimage.png"" alt=""inline image test""/></html>"
Mail.MimeFormatted = True
Mail.Message.AddRelatedBodyPart("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.png", "myimage.png", CdoReferenceTypeName)
Mail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<myimage.png>"
Mail.Fields.Update
```

#### Method 2: base64 encoded binary image in html

**You Need to add reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0 (or v3.0)**

```
' Some data you'll need to build your htmlmessage:
Dim encodedImage As String
Dim htmlBody as String
encodedImage = EncodeFile("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.png")

' Example htmlBody, look at the img src !
htmlBody = "<html><head></head><body><p><img src=""data:image/png;base64," & encodedImage & """ alt=""base64 encoded image"" /></p></body></html>"

' Extra helper function to base64 encode binary files
' Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134022/3090890
Public Function EncodeFile(strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded

    ' Variables for encoding
    Dim objXML
    Dim objDocElem

    ' Variable for reading binary picture
    Dim objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)

    ' Create XML Document object and root node
    ' that will contain the data
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"

    ' Set binary value
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

    ' Get base64 value
    EncodeFile = objDocElem.Text

    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

Thanks to these sources I could help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134022/3090890
https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/173569-embed-images-in-cdo-mail-message/4

Answer (score 0):

Note: **base64** *images won't work on GMail* - google strips such data off (from experience building my automated emails). My solution in a similar case was to upload attachments to a cloud service like AWS S3, then add link to HTML body e.g

```
<img src='https://my-email-attachments.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cats.png'>
```

Another way would be to save your image locally on your system ([Example code for saving an Excel shape to a file](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-save-as-picture-file-excel)), update your HTML Template so it conforms to MIME Standards (as show in [Method 1 by @Piemol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754048/6612762)).

Deciding on whether to Attach or Link, depends on your business needs and that's really a whole other question.