# Gmail Excel VBA add image as body

Tags: excel, vba, automation, gmail

I'm currently trying to write an automation VBA script that will send out email with image in the body using Gmail application. Below is my code that I have tried and, so far, no image has been showing in the email body. I could only add the image as an attachment and not as a body.

```
Sub email_CDO()

Dim month As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook


For iRow = 2 To wb.Sheets("client_list").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "waiyan01@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "foukxizyifqoshhu"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = wb.Sheets("client_list").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .ReplyTo = "waiyan01@gmail.com"
        .From = "waiyan01@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "--" & " " & month & " " & page_name
    
        .HTMLBody = "Hello " & page_name & _
            "<br><br>--" & _
            "<br><br>--" & _
            "<br><br>--" & _
            "<img src='C:\Users\foodpanda\Desktop\Email\Storage\email.jpg'>" & _
            "<br><br><font size='1' font color='grey'>???????????????????????????.</font>"
        If .To <> "" Then
            .AddAttachment "C:\Users\Desktop\Email\Storage\example.jpg"
            .Send
        End If

    End With

Next iRow

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
   
MsgBox "All email have been sent!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65705296/2685412)? It does not have an accepted answer, but I think the discussion will give you some leads.

Comment: Seems like method1 from this answer at L42's link should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change those lines

```
    "<img src='C:\Users\foodpanda\Desktop\Email\Storage\email.jpg'>" & _
    "<br><br><font size='1' font color='grey'>???????????????????????????.</font>"
If .To <> "" Then
    .AddAttachment "C:\Users\Desktop\Email\Storage\example.jpg"
    .Send
End If
```

with those updated lines,maybe this will help

```
  "<img src='cid:email.jpg'>" & _
  "<br><br><font size='1' font color='grey'>???????????????????????????.</font>"
 If .To <> "" Then
  Dim objBP As Object:  Set objBP = iMsg.AddRelatedBodyPart("C:\Users\foodpanda\Desktop\Email\Storage\email.jpg", "email.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
    objBP.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<email.jpg>"
    objBP.Fields.update
.AddAttachment "C:\Users\foodpanda\Desktop\Email\Storage\email.jpg"
.AddAttachment "C:\Users\Desktop\Email\Storage\example.jpg"
.Send
```

End If
And make sure that the file email.jpg exist and the path is correct

Comment: I've changed the lines and the images did not include in the body