# Reading a base64 image string with VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, base64

**QUESTION**

How to read or convert a base64 image string with  Microsoft Access vba?

**REQUIREMENTS**

A base64 image string is stored in a **ms sqlserver** database as below:

*BASE64*

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...
```

Using vba I am attempting to read the string from the database using microsoft **vba**.

---

I know vba is capable of reading a string from the database to output the image on screen as I currently achieve this result by reading the image as a **hex** sting as below:

*HEX*

```
89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484...
```

So how can vba read a base64 image string to display the image on screen within Microsoft Access?

Comment: Why do people down vote without cause or explanation? Offer suggestion how to improve the question and consequently the website.

Comment: what is the database, really SQL Server or Access?  and what are you really using to connect to it, vba or VB6 (which is not a new or efficient web technology).

Comment: Data base is sqlserver. Reading the database is vba.

Comment: One possible reason for the downvote is that your question is vague. Q: "Is it possible...?" A: Yes, it is. Anything more specific will depend on what you want to do with the image after it has been decoded. "Change is now required to accomodate new and more efficient web technologies" is not an adequate description. As for the decoding method itself did you by chance do a web search for 'access base64 decode' ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you this is helpful I will revise my question to compensate.

Comment: Old Q, but it'd be nice if you could link to whatever method you found for converting Hex->image

Comment: @Greedo I'm afraid this question is past it's cell by date. I don't recall but I don't think I converted at all, I ended up saving both formats in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know vba is capable of reading a string from the database to output the image on screen as I currently achieve this result by reading the image as a hex sting as below:
>
> HEX
>
> 89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484...

So really what you are asking is how to decode the Base64 string to a hex string. In that case you just want strip off the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix and pass the rest to a function like `Decode64()` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170018/2144390).

Comment: That looks like what I am after. I will try it out. Thanks