# Convert an embedded Excel Picture into an Object

Tags: vba, excel

I created a logo in Publisher.
Using TechSmith Snagit, I captured the image and saved as a JPEG.
I fetched the image inside of Excel and placed it in a properly sized cell(s)

I don't want to have a file that has the image (have seen in researching some solutions) -- Nevertheless, everything must be self-contained in my Excel vba Application.

Excel (2013) has a tendency to either erase the image or it creeps when the app is opened on other displays. (And it does this with ActiveX Controls, too)

So... a friend wrote code that stretches or centers ActiveX Controls inside cells.  Works brilliantly, except I want to apply the code to the Picture (say Picture 12) ... the Logo ...

If I could convert the Picture into an Object (similar to a CommandButton or a SpinButton, I think the code would work.

My work around had been to insert the logo as a BitMap into a CommandButton, and then apply the stretching code to the button... BUT I have image size limitations and the Bitmap is of low resolution, which makes my beautiful logo look terrible.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use base64

[Inserting an Image into a sheet using Base64 in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126617/inserting-an-image-into-a-sheet-using-base64-in-vba#39222080)

https://www.base64-image.de/