# Read file to string in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a sub that will use an HTTP post to upload a file to a server. I've already worked out all of the code to actually sent the post request, but I can't figure out how to get the file into the appropriate format. The server is expecting the file's bytes as a string, but no matter what approach I take to creating the string the values don't match up with what's expected.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim TestBytes() As Byte
    Dim TestByte As Variant

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.name For Binary Access Read As #FileNum    'Open document to write to string
    ReDim TestBytes(LOF(FileNum) - 1)
    Get FileNum, , TestBytes
    Close FileNum
    For Each TestByte In TestBytes
        TestString = TestString & Hex(TestByte)
    Next TestByte
    Debug.Print TestString
End Sub
```

The output looks something like this (truncated, as the full string is obviously quite long):

```
504B3414060800021076DD8E8C9D130825B436F6E74656E745F54797065735D2E786D6C20...
```

The problem is, the example output I have says it *should* look like this:

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCuTjGvewEAAAIGAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACA...
```

I assumed the problem was that my test code is trying to encode the bytes as hex values, whereas the example is obviously not in hex, but when I just try to output the file's bytes directly as a string I get a lot of invalid characters. Here's the code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim TestBytes() As Byte
    Dim TestByte As Variant

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.name For Binary Access Read As #FileNum    'Open document to write to string
    TestString = String$(LOF(FileNum), Chr(32))    'Fill string with blank space to set string length
    Get FileNum, , TestString   'Write binary data from file to string
    Debug.Print TestString
End Sub
```

And here's the output:

```
PK     ! vÝŽŒ  p    ...
```

Is there something I'm missing as to how I can encode the bytes to get output that's encoded the same as the example output? When performing a similar operation in another language (e.g. Java using [readFileToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)), how is the string encoded?

Comment: `UEsDBB...` looks like Base64.  The format is controlled by the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.  You do not need to encode however, you can write the bytes directly - the way you do this will depend upon how you construct the multipart/form-data request (assuming thats what your using).

Comment: (Your hex approach is invalid btw even if it were allowed because you need to pad single values with a leading `0`)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I'm still pretty inexperienced in programming in general, I was unaware of Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Alex K.'s advice in the comments above, and the Base64 encoding function [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba), I came to this solution:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim TestBytes() As Byte
    Dim TestByte As Variant

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.name For Binary Access Read As #FileNum    'Open document to write to string
    TestString = String$(LOF(FileNum), Chr(32))    'Fill string with blank space to set string length
    Get FileNum, , TestString   'Write binary data from file to string
    TestString = EncodeBase64(TestString)

    Debug.Print TestString
End Sub

Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String
  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Which outputs the correct string:

```
UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCuTjGvewEAAAIGAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACA...
```