# Curl to VBA Conversion

Tags: excel, vba, curl

What is this api code's VBA equivalent (for Name.com Domain Check API):

**curl -u 'username:token' 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability' -X POST --data '{"domainNames":["example.org"]}'**

Tried:

```
Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") '
url = "https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability"
request.Open "POST", url, False
request.setRequestHeader "username:token", "???:???"
or 
request.SetCredentials "username", "token", 0
request.setRequestHeader "domainNames", Range("C1").Value & ".com"
request.Send
MsgBox request.ResponseText
```

It says: "message:","unauthenticated"

Note: 
for GoDaddy Domain Availability API, that conversion works:

**curl -X GET -H"Authorization: sso-key [API_KEY]:[API_SECRET]""https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain="**

VBA:

```
url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?domain=" & Range(CellC).Value & ".com"
request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "sso-key ???:???"
```

(username and token/key (???) are hidden)

Also, **for "whois.internic.net" query, a (running) VBA code example** will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Range("C1").Value`? I know nothing about curl, but that Range value jumps out wrong to me

Comment: Have you reviewed the other similar questions on SO?

Comment: Yes, several internet resources reviewed.

Comment: If those did not help, without real credentials to access that site, it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: You don't have anything in your send line where POST body should go

Comment: According to the documentation your body should have the list of domains in the format something like: data = '{"domainNames":["example.org"]}'

Answer (score 1):

You need to base64 encode the authentication details and pass in headers and pass the list of domains in the body. I have used [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the json response. After adding the bas you need to add the reference shown below. Also, add reference to Microsoft xml

```
Public Sub GetResults()
    Dim data As String, json As Object '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    data = "{""domainNames"":[""google.com""]}"
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", "https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
            EncodeBase64("username" + ":" + "Token")
        .send data
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        Dim result As Object
        For Each result In json("results")
            Debug.Print result("domainName")
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String


  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = Application.Clean(objNode.text)

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

base64 function taken from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060527094535/http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp%20---)/[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169945/6241235).

If you know python you can more simply do:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}

data = '{"domainNames":["google.com"]}'

result = requests.post('https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability', data=data, headers = headers, auth=('username','token')).json()
print(result['results'])
```

Comment: Did you try this please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try XMLHTTP and see if it makes any difference including username and token in open method?

```
url = "https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
request.open("POST", url, False, "username", "token")
request.setRequestHeader "domainNames", Range("C1").Value & ".com"
request.Send

MsgBox request.ResponseText
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use curl directly (via the windows shell):

For the code below, you set a reference to the `Windows Script Host Object Model` for early binding.

Of course, I can't test it as given since it returns "permission denied" which, I assume, is due to the invalid username:token.

Note the `""` escaped quotes for the quote marks included within the quoted string.

```
Option Explicit
Sub curl()
    Const strCurl As String = """username:token"" ""https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability"" -X POST --data ""{""domainNames"":[""example.org""]}"""
    Dim WSH As WshShell, lErrCode As Long
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sBasePath As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim strJson As String

    sTemp = Environ("Temp") & "\FileList.txt"



Set WSH = New WshShell
lErrCode = WSH.Run("CMD /c curl -u" & strCurl & " > " & sTemp, xlHidden, True)

'lErrCode = WSH.Run("CMD /c tree """ & sBasePath & """ /F /A > " & sTemp, xlHidden, True)

If Not lErrCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Problem " & "Error Code " & lErrCode
    Exit Sub
End If


Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(sTemp, ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
strJson = TS.ReadAll
TS.Close

FSO.DeleteFile sTemp
Set FSO = Nothing
Set WSH = Nothing

Stop 'see what's in the string.
     'if it worked, then you can parse the results

End Sub
```

Comment: via Windows PowerShell and: curl -u 'username:token' 'https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability' -X POST --data '{"domainNames":"example.com"}' it says: {"message":"Invalid Argument","details":"Error occurred during parsing: Cannot decode json string."}

Comment: @OptNames As I wrote above, it will be hard to help you without `username:token`. Not sure why you are commenting here on your results using PowerShell, but if you do use PS, you need to call `curl.exe` since `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`