# How to encode username and password and pass then in header in VBA POST method

Tags: json, vba, post, base64, parameter-passing

I am a self-taught and got stuck in a problem. If you can please give me a little help.

I'm doing a query via API on a website. I can create JSON but can't enter username and password.

**They report (https://api.braspress.com/home):**

*Depending on the chosen language or platform you will need to 'encode' your username and password and pass them in the request header Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50ZTpjbGllbnRl. If your language or library already does this internally skip this step.
For other cases, use the website https://www.base64encode.org*

**curl usage:**

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50ZTpjbGllbnRl" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cnpjRemetente":60701190000104,"cnpjDestinatario":30539356867,"modal":"R","tipoFrete":"1", "cepOrigem":2323000,"cepDestino":7093090,"vlrMercadoria":100.00,"peso":50.55,"volumes":100}, "cubagem":[{"altura":0.46,"largura":0.67,"comprimento":0.67,"volumes":10}]' -X POST https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json
```

**javascript usage**

```
var authorizationBasic = 'Y2xpZW50ZTpjbGllbnRl';
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json',
data: '{"cnpjRemetente":60701190000104,"cnpjDestinatario":30539356867,"modal":"R","tipoFrete":"1", "cepOrigem":2323000,"cepDestino":7093090,"vlrMercadoria":100.00,"peso":50.55,"volumes":10,"cubagem":[{"altura":0.46,"largura":0.67,"comprimento":0.67,"volumes":10}]}',
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic,
},
success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
},
error: function (req, status, error) {
console.log(error);
}
});
```

**What I have done so far:**

```
Public Sub ConsultaFrete()
    Dim job As cJobject, jo As cJobject, cj As cJobject
    Dim body As String
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim myurl As String
    

'Call OptimizeCode_Begin

myurl = "https://api.braspress.com/v1/cotacao/calcular/json"


Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False

    Set job = New cJobject
    body = ""

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization: Basic", "MDU5MTAxNjIwMDAxODA6UG93ZGVybWl4MkAh"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"



With job.init(Nothing, "")
        
    .add "cnpjRemetente", "05910162000180" 'Chave primaria número exclusivo
    .add "cnpjDestinatario", "05198251000146"
    .add "modal", "R"
    .add "tipoFrete", "1"
    .add "cepOrigem", "11015201"
    .add "cepDestino", "48903500"
    .add "vlrMercadoria", "486.00"
    .add "peso", "14.00"
    .add "volumes", "2"
    With .add("cubagem").addArray.add
        .add "altura", "0.23"
        .add "largura", "0.44"
        .add "comprimento", "0.65"
        .add "volumes", "2"
    End With
    

End With
       
    body = job.serialize
    body = Mid(body, 2, Len(body) - 2)
    Debug.Print body
    
xmlhttp.send body

Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you Raymond, I saw this, but I couldn't understand how to pass the password.

Comment: Paste the function in the answer in your module and assign a string variable to the function with your password as the parameter? E.g `encodedPW = EncodeBase64("yourpassword")` @Danilo

Comment: With your answer @RaymondWu and some research I found:

authUser = "USER"
    authPass = "PASSWORD"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64(authUser & ":" & authPass)

TKS