# VBA error to encode the consumer key and secret as base64

Tags: excel, vba

What is wrong with the following code to encode the consumer key and secret as base64:

```
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByVal input As String) As String
    
    Dim data() As Byte
    Dim result As String
    
    data = StrConv(input, vbFromUnicode)
    result = Application.EncodeBase64(data)
    
    EncodeBase64 = result
    
End Function
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Gives compile error, expected identifier and at the line  data = StrConv(input, vbFromUnicode)

Comment: It looks like `input` is not allowed as variable name - try renaming it to e.g. `strInput`.

Comment: It solved the identifier error. Thanks! It gave new error at line result = Application.EncodeBase64(data)
object does not support this property or method

Comment: Didn't recognize that: but there is not `EncodeBase64` method in VBA. But look e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/169907/16578424