# Create Token UPS API oauth2 in VBA

Tags: vba, base64, token, ups

Trying to convert the old UPS API to new oauth2.0. Getting error message as:

> {"response":{"errors":[{"code":"10400","message":"Invalid/Missing Authorization Header"}]}}

This is from UPS sample code:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  -u {clientID}:{clientSecret} \
  https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'x-merchant-id: string' \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

```vb
Sub POST_Method_Example()
Dim strHead As String, strClientId As String, strClientSecret As String
strClientId = "xxx"
strClientSecret = "xxx"
strHead = strClientId & ":" & strClientSecret

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64(strHead)
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "x-merchant-id", "string"
        .send "grant_type=client_credentials"
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With

End Sub
```

Updated with BASE64 encoding

Comment: Is your `{clientID}:{clientSecret}` Base64-encoded?  Assuming this is what you're following: https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/GenerateToken

Comment: No I did not encode to Base64.

Comment: If the URL I posted is the one you're following, then you need to base64-encode.  Se (eg) https://stackoverflow.com/a/169945/478884

Comment: Changed using Base64, still getting error.

Comment: Examples have `grant_type = authorization_code` not `grant_type = client_credentials`

Comment: Update: It worked using EncodeBase64 encoding from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169907/how-do-i-base64-encode-a-string-efficiently-using-excel-vba/169945#169945

Comment: You can post an answer with your working code and accept it.

Comment: Do you want to post that using BASE64 for the clientID and clientPW will solve it, you helped me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/GenerateToken the `{clientID}:{clientSecret}` needs to be Base64-encoded.

See (eg) https://stackoverflow.com/a/169945/478884 for a VBA approach to B64 encoding